# How to clear all <div>s’ contents inside a parent <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I have a div `<div id="masterdiv">` which has several child `<div>`s.

Example:

```
<div id="masterdiv">
  <div id="childdiv1" />
  <div id="childdiv2" />
  <div id="childdiv3" />
</div>
```

How to clear the contents of all child `<div>`s inside the master `<div>` using jQuery?

Comment: I re-tagged your question because it's not related to Asp.net MVC (as you've tagged it) in any way shape or form.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer that uses `.empty()`. It is the most performant way to do it

Answer (score 282, accepted):

```
jQuery('#masterdiv div').html('');
```

Comment: Can we clone the html and manipulate on that?
like var tmp =  $('<div>').append($('#masterdiv').clone()).remove().html();
and get the divs inside #masterdiv of tmp and clear the contents and return

Comment: Using `.empty()` would be a better option as no string parsing is involved.  It operates directly on the DOM object model.

Comment: `empty()` also clears all the content that is generated with jQuery.

Answer (score 471):

jQuery's [`empty()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) function does just that:

```
$('#masterdiv').empty();
```

clears the master `div`.

```
$('#masterdiv div').empty();
```

clears all the child `div`s, but leaves the master intact.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/empty/ it is true but i dont know why Quentin answer accepted :)

Comment: This clears more than what was asked for in the original question -- you should use a more [specific selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701973/clear-all-divs-contents-inside-a-div/3543068#3543068).

Comment: Wow, thanks you Drew for pointing this out 1.5 years later :) Fixed.

Answer (score 23):

Use jQuery's CSS selector syntax to select all `div` elements inside the element with id `masterdiv`.  Then call [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to clear the contents.

```
$('#masterdiv div').empty();
```

Using `text('')` or `html('')` will cause some string parsing to take place, which generally is a bad idea when working with the DOM.  Try and use DOM manipulation methods that do not involve string representations of DOM objects wherever possible.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is a `jQuery` related question, but I believe someone might get here expecting a pure `Javascript` solution. So, if you were trying to do this using `js`, you could use the `innerHTML` property and set it to an empty string.

```
document.getElementById('masterdiv').innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: this was the top result on Google when searching for how to empty a div. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

> jQuery recommend you use ".empty()",".remove()",".detach()"

if you needed delete all element in element, use this code :

```
$('#target_id').empty();
```

if you needed delete all element, Use this code:

```
$('#target_id').remove();
```

> i and jQuery group not recommend for use **SET FUNCTION** like .html() .attr() .text() , what is that? it's **IF YOU WANT TO SET ANYTHING YOU NEED**

ref :https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/

Answer (score 12):

If all the divs inside that masterdiv needs to be cleared, it this.

```
$('#masterdiv div').html('');
```

else, you need to iterate on all the div children of #masterdiv, and check if the id starts with childdiv.

```
$('#masterdiv div').each(
    function(element){
        if(element.attr('id').substr(0, 8) == "childdiv")
        {
            element.html('');
        }
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 11):

**The better way is :**

```
 $( ".masterdiv" ).empty();
```

Comment: This selects all elements with class "masterdiv", not id "masterdiv", as per the questions - just a note.

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#masterdiv div").text("");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#masterdiv > *").text("")
```

or

```
$("#masterdiv").children().text("")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#div_id').empty();
```

or

```
$('.div_class').empty();
```

Works Fine to remove contents inside a div

Comment: Duplicate of Emil Ivanov's answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use .empty() function to clear all the child elements

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#button").click(function () {
   //only the content inside of the element will be deleted
   $("#masterdiv").empty();
  });
 });
```

To see the comparison between jquery .empty(), .hide(), .remove() and .detach() follow here http://www.voidtricks.com/jquery-empty-hide-remove-detach/

Answer (score 5):

When you are appending data into div by id using any service or database, first try it empty, like this:

```
var json = jsonParse(data.d);
$('#divname').empty();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#masterdiv div[id^='childdiv']").each(function(el){$(el).empty();});
```

or

```
$("#masterdiv").find("div[id^='childdiv']").each(function(el){$(el).empty();});
```

Answer (score 0):

try them if it help.

`$('.div_parent .div_child').empty();`

`$('#div_parent #div_child').empty();`

Comment: why "-1". I was only trying to help?