# Hide <p> when the user clicks in the intern href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done this document in JQuery, when the user clicks on the different internal links, this loads a with div id = "change" that "deletes" the content.

So far it deletes the image without problems, but the

inside no, I understand this only works for images and not for texts, but I do not find that script that can delete the text.

HTML

```
 <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a id="page2">Abertura de cajas</a></li>
```

All the content inside the div "cambio" should be erased at the moment the users clicks on the href (see above)

```
<div id="cambio">
<div id="text_main">

    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>

</div>   




<div><img id="logotipo" src=".\docu2_files\imagenes\ricoh.jpg"></div>

</div>
```

The Jquery loads the content of the required html and deletes the content in the id "cambio"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#page1").click(function(){
         $("#change").css("display", "none");
           $('#result').load('./docu2_files/docs/control_dia.html');
       });
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle to show your problem ?

Comment: Could you explain more about html?

Comment: You have framed your question as if we know what you are working on. Please provide more details about what you already have and what you want as output.

Comment: Edited, hope this will help you

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701973/clear-all-divs-contents-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) to ' clear ' all the content ( including the `#text-main` div ) from inside the `#cambio`

> Description: empty()  Remove all child nodes of the set of matched
>   elements from the DOM.

see snippet below or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/503wan2p/1/)

```js
$("#page2").click(function(){
    $("#cambio").empty()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a id="page2">Abertura de cajas</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="cambio">
<div id="text_main">

    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>

</div> 
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I added that in the Jquery file:

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#page1").click(function(){
 $("ul li").click(function(){
     $("#cambio > #text_main ").empty()
 })
        $('#result').load('./docu2_files/docs/control_dia.html');
       });


But isn't working.

Comment: well. i just made an example for you . `ul li` in my example is your `#page1 ` in yours . ( change in my code `ul li` with `#page2` plus you didn't share anything about the #result div ( where is it located in your HTML ? ) .

Comment: I mean it does disable the image but the text still there.

Comment: it cannot be right. as you can see in my example , the text dissapears . and again...what image? in your example there is no image

Comment: There's an image: "<div><img id="logotipo" src=".\docu2_files\imagenes\ricoh.jpg"></div>"

Comment: Nothing, the image dissapears but the text stay.

Comment: in my answer. can you see that the text is dissapearing ? so it must be from other code you have

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div><img id="logotipo" src=".\docu2_files\imagenes\ricoh.jpg" onclick="hideFunction()"></div>
```

Then for your JavaScript / JQuery:

```
function hideFunction(){
    $("#text_main").hide();
}
```