# How remove specific code or attribute from html using java or jquery

Tags: java, jquery

Firstly i want to tell that i have zero knowledge regarding all this. So forgive me if i say something wrong. i have this code, cant paste it here as its a big one and exceeds the post limit.

**Summary**
I have put the code in text file and you can view it here,
[view the code on this link](http://superbabyboutique.com/tablecode.txt)

I am using this code in my product descriptions on an ecommerce platform. It is imported automatically to my store, so can't edit it. Only option i have is to make changes via java or jquery. So please dont suggest solutions which involve editing the code first and then applying java.

I want a java or jquery solution which implements the changes i want when the page loads.

This is the link to screenshot on how this code looks in my product description,

[view the screenshot](http://superbabyboutique.com/screenshot.jpg)

**What I Want**
I want a java or jquery solution which implements the below changes on page load. Its ok if your solution includes different or several codes.

1. I want to exactly remove this below line from the code,

```html
style="width: 676px;"
```

2. Thn i want the below line to be removed exactly from the code,

```html
<table id="mainpage" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" cellspacing="0">
```

3. (optional) If possible - I want to clear background color of rows i.e black, grey, red, pink etc etc and make it transparent or use the page background color. I want to clear any kind of formatting, but i want to have text in bold the same way and so the table as well and i also want the same font size, any formatting except that can be cleared. And i want all the text in black color.

That's it... :) ...the first 2 i mentioned are important...3rd problem is optional...if anyone can solve all the 3...it will be great... :) ...Also send me the solution in a way that i easily determine which solution is for which question... :) ..Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code for the `width: 676px` is actually `<div id="left" style="width: 676px;">` - so please explain what you are wanting.  Are you wanting to remove the whole div's content?  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701973/clear-all-divs-contents-inside-a-div

Comment: how is it duplicate?

Comment: part 1 is to remove remove content from a div, so is part 2 - maybe you have not explained your question well if you think this does not solve your problem.  If it does not solve your problem please edit your question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I can re-open